# Add controls attribute to video element using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to figure out how to add controls to a video using jQuery.
 I have tried the following but it did not work:

```
$('.video-js').attr('controls', 'controls');
```

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try this

```
$('.video-js').attr('controls',true);
```

Alternatively if you're using jQuery 1.6+ you may/should use

```
 $(".video-js").prop("controls",true);
```

Comment: This works on the iPad but doesn't seem to be working on the desktop. I'll try again though.

Comment: Not sure why this didn't work before. Works now. Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/chrisabrams/yYAY2/

Comment: Use $(".video-js").get(0).setAttribute('controls',true)